# Set operations with scipy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, set

Python has a very nice 'set' data structure which is basically an unordered list that enables set operations.
I would have been tempted to use such a data structure for the following purpose:

I have a set of datapoints from a survey (each point is a two-element Scipy/numpy array) that can be divided in different subsets according to the gender and marital status of the respondents.

Unfortunately, *Python sets don't seem to allow so-called mutable objects such as numpy arays and lists*.
I could use tuples for my datapoints, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Ideally, I would like to have several unordered lists (sets) of datapoints that I could intersect, union, etc.. - and which I could iterate over (both over the individual datapoints, and over the list of sets for plotting purposes).

So my question is: Is using sets of tuples the only way to do what I want in this context ? Is it really impossible in Python to have sets of mutable elements (such as numpy arrays) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[python-sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) must be [hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) in python. So you may define a `class datapoint` and implement `__hash__(self)` and `__eq__(self)` as a function of its elements and add instances of those into your set.

Or maybe you want to use a [named tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). I have not tested them but they implement `__hash__` and `__eq__` also. They are still tuples but at least, they may be accessed in a more readable fashion.

Answer (score -1):

Sets of mutable objects is a complex concept. What should

```
a = set([]); 
a.add (object1);
a.add (object2);
object3 = object1;
object1 = object2;
object1 = object3;
print (len(a));
```

print? You could say the set should have collapsed object1 and object2 when they were equal, but that's basically unimplementable. Sticking `print(len(a))` in the middle shouldn't change a--len should be a pure function--but that would mean that `set` has to store multiple objects and figure out which ones are the same when operations are done on them. Of course

```
print (len(a))
object1 = object3
print (len(a))
```

printing 1 2 is a bit surprising, too. Implementing sets over mutable objects efficiently and with reasonable semantics is very hard, which is why Python didn't try.

Edit: Then try

```
a = set([])
a.add (mutable_array([1,2]));
a.add (mutable_array([1,3]));
for i in a:
     i[1] = 2
print (len(a));
```

The point stands: if you stick a mutable object in a set, either that set's going to end up with duplicates or the set is going to have to track what's changing in them.

Comment: You seem confused about _object_ mutability vs _reference_ mutability. Assignment statements like `object3 = object1` change the references in the local namespace. They don't change the objects themselves. Thus, you haven't demonstrated anything about the mutability of the objects referenced by the `set`. In your example, `len(a)` would output `2` (if you'd been allowed to add `object1` and `object2` in the first place, and they weren't equal).

Comment: If they're mutable, they can mutate, can't they?

Comment: `append` is an example of an operation that mutates list objects. Consider the difference between `l = [1]; l.append[3]` and `l = [1]; l = [1,3]`. The former mutates `l`; the latter throws away the old list and forms a new one, which is what you've done in your first two examples. Your new example is correct though, and is the reason that mutable types tend not to be hashable (and therefore can't be used in a `set`).

Comment: The point is, this is not a Python problem. Truly mutable types can't be hashable for the purposes of data structures, because you can change what they would hash to without moving them in the data structure. He can't write custom code to do this that reliably works, not in Python or any language.

Comment: That's exactly right. The first two examples in your answer don't illustrate this, though. You should remove them, and replace them with what you wrote in that comment.